# How to remove ending commas in a list of ints with python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function I wrote in python that simple makes a horizontal list of int.  I modified the print statement so that the list would print with commas, but the function adds one after the last int.

Any ideas as how to get rid of it?

```
num = list(range(20))

def count(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        # i+1 add in order to remove beginning zero.
        print(i+1,end=',')

count(num)
```

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,

Comment: Thanks Skatox, for my purposes it would be better if the list wasn't in brackets, is there anyway to clear them?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
num = list(range(20))
l = []
def count(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        l.append(i+1)

count(num)
print(l)
```

Outpout:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
>   20]

---

You can also modify it to this:

```
def count(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        # i+1 add in order to remove beginning zero.
        if i < len(x)-1:
            print(i+1, end=',')
        else:
            print(i+1)
```

Output:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20

Comment: Thanks Chandan, this is exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Add each number to a string and then print the string minus the last character:

```
   num = list(range(20))

    def count(x):
        s = ""
        for i in range(len(x)):
            # i+1 add in order to remove beginning zero.
            s += str(i+1) + ","
        print(s[:-1])

    count(num)
```

Output:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
num = list(range(20))

def count(x):
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        print(i+1,end=',')
    print(len(x))

count(num)
```

Comment: GAVD awesome fix! I would have never thought of that, I can't stand that its so obvious!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a function, an output sequence can be processed with the range command:

```
num   = range(1,21,1)
print num
```

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

Print without the braces:

```
num = range(1,21,1)
print str(num).strip('[]')
```

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20

User chooses start and ending numbers somewhere earlier in the code:

```
start = 56
end   = 69
num   = range(start, end + 1)
print str(num).strip('[]')
```

Output is:

56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69

User supplies start and stop interactivly:

```
start = raw_input('Choose start')
end   = raw_input('Choose end')
num   = range(start, end + 1)
print str(num).strip('[]')
```

Comment: Hey drPete, thank you very much for your insight, I hadn't considered letting range do all the work.  The only problem is that I need the parameter of range to be a variable, as I am uncertain what the user will input, and for my purposes the output would look better if it was not in brackets.  Thx

Comment: Sal, didn't know where the list originated. Print without the braces: print str(num).strip('[]').

Answer (score 0):

A better function name would be `display`, and the function you want is `str.join()`:

```
def display(list_data):
    print(', '.join(list_data))
```

The thing to keep in mind is the pieces to join must be strings, so you may need to convert:

```
', '.join([str(i) for i in list_data])
```

Comment: Dang Bro! I'm such a noob, this is what I needed, I tried it but the .join() will not work with an int object, only strings.  I also tried .append() but no good. Do you know of one for ints?  Thanks